# storyboardの遷移でエラーが出ます。(segueを使用しない方法で実装)

Tags: ios, swift

storyboardの遷移でエラーが出ます。調べても解決しなかったため、質問させて頂きます。

<<目的>>
ViewControllerからListViewControllerへ遷移させたい。

<<失敗箇所>>
ViewControllerのs.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifierの行

<<エラー内容>>
Unknown class LlistViewController in Interface Builder file.
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x1082ed7f8) to 'ListViewController' (0x1051a7f40).

尚、ListViewController.storyboardのStoryboardIDには ListViewControllerと設定している

<<詳細>>

ViewController.swift

```
    func onClick() {
        let s = UIStoryboard(name: "ListViewController", bundle: nil)
        let vc = s.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ListViewController") as! ListViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }
```

ListViewController.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ListViewController: UITableViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label_title: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

[image: ListViewController.storyboardの画面]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Unknown class LlistViewController in Interface Builder file.

Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x1082ed7f8) to 'ListViewController' (0x1051a7f40).*
私が今まで見た全ての事例でこのようなエラーが出た場合には、1つの例外もなく100%がStoryboardへのCustomClassの設定ミスでした。

*尚、ListViewController.storyboardのStoryboardIDには ListViewControllerと設定している*
StoryboardIDというのは、複数のオブジェクトを区別するためにつける単なる目印となる文字列ですので、それと生成されるクラスとは関係ありません。

問題は画面写真でStoryboard IDの上に写っているこの内容の部分です。
**Custom Class**
Class [ListViewController]
Module [None]

Storyboardからインスタンスを作成する場合に、NibLoaderは"ListViewController"と言う正式名称を持つクラスを探しに行きますが、あなたのプロジェクトの中にはそんな名前のクラスはないので、Storyboardに貼り付けられた部品の属性から最も適当と思われるクラス(今回の場合UITableViewController)のインスタンスを作ります。ところが、それをListViewControllerに強制キャストしようとしているので、そこでキャスト落ちしているわけです。

Swiftで書いたクラスの正式名称(Javaで言うところのFQCN)には、(@objcなどを付加しない限り)クラス名の前にモジュール名が入り、"{ProductModuleName}.ListViewController"と言った感じになります。つまり、自分がSwiftで書いたクラスをstoryboard中に指定する場合には、Moduleの部分をNoneにしてはいけません。

Storyboardの該当部分を修正し、Moduleの部分を正しく指定して実行しなおしてみてください。(あるいは、`@objc(クラス名)`と言ったアノテーションを付加して、モジュール名のない`クラス名`を正式のクラス名にしてしまうという手もあります。)

Comment: ご回答有難う御座います。以下のページを参考にmodule名を正しく入力し、実行しました。
http://qiita.com/ikke/items/9304d52b0153adec4a41
エラー内容は変わったものの、依然として、遷移に成功できませんでした。

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7fb929518280>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'ListViewController''

Comment: エラー内容でググッてこういう内容の記事にそって、修正してもダメでした。http://qiita.com/satomin/items/c8cb6f815e6dc0b6beba

Comment: 尚、今回のエラーはAppDelegateのファイル内にて発生しております。

Comment: 症状を再現できないので確実なことは言えないのですが、ご報告のエラーメッセージは「指定されたstoryboardの中に指定のIDを持つview controllerが含まれていない」と言う意味です。エラー発生箇所がAppDelegateと表示されているのであれば、設定ファイルの中に不整合があって、起動用のstoryboard(通常ならMain.storyboard)の中に、存在しないListViewControllerと言うIDのview controllerを探しに行く状態になってしまっているのだと思います。プロジェクトのTARGETS設定のGeneralに存在するMain Interfaceがどのstoryboardファイルを指しているかとそこで指されているstoryboardファイル中にIs Initial ViewControllerがチェックされたview controllerが存在するか確かめてみてください。Xcodeはstoryboardのコンパイルの際に変な挙動をすることがあるので、設定を確かめたら一度クリーンビルドしてみた方がいいでしょう。もし症状を再現できるプロジェクトをどこかのファイル共有サイト等にアップできるのであれば、調べてみますのでご連絡ください。

Comment: 度々ご回答頂き有難う御座います。プロジェクトのTARGETS設定のGeneralに存在するMain InterfaceはMain.storybordになってました。

また、Is Initial ViewControllerがチェックされたview controllerが存在してました。

ファイル共有サイトにアップロードはできますが、不特定多数の方に見せたくない（見せられるような内容でない）ため、以下のメールアドレスに空メールに近い内容で構いませんので、お送り頂けないでしょうか？そちらに返答する形で、ファイル共有サイトのURLを送りたいと考えております。

ycloud001あっとまーくgmail.com

あっとまーくは@に変換して下さい。


お手数ですが、宜しくお願いします。

Comment: ご連絡いただいたプロジェクトを拝見しました。前のコメントは大間違いのミスリーディングなものだったようで、ListViewController.storyboardのViewControllerのStoryboard IDの値が「`LlistViewController`」になっていました。(ここに間違いがあるとAppDelegateにエラーがあるかのように表示されるのは初めて知りました。最初から、一番疑わしいStoryboard IDを再度チェックするようアドバイスできていればよかったのですが、申し訳ありません。)コードの方は、`"ListViewController"`でIDを指定していますから、IDが違うので「見つからない」というエラーになっているものです。私の回答に関連があるのかどうか不明でしたので長々とコメントしてしまいましたが、この部分を修正して無事に解決できた場合、他の問題点(もう少し直さないといけない部分があるようです)はコメントにせずに(必要であれば)別件として質問してください。

Comment: コードまでレビュー頂き本当に有難う御座いました。
おかげで問題を解決することができました。
原因がわからず一人でモヤモヤとした日々を過ごしていましたが、おかげさまで解決できました。

今回の一番の原因はタイポかつ、そのタイポに気が付かなかったことです。
今後はタイポということも念頭において注意深くデバッグしてみたいと思います。

ありがとうございました。